# Can I Place a Program Written in the Java Programming Language on the Internet in a Way that Others can Run it for Free Without Security Issues?

Tags: java, security, applet

I've been going through a very frustrating time trying to distribute my program and I could really use some help.

So it all started a long time ago when I decided to try and teach myself C++. I thought I'd learn by doing by trying to create a text adventure with basic code. I managed to create an executable file that worked and cheerfully submitted it to a website that sometimes hosted content similar to what I created.

My submission was rejected out of hand, as no one wanted to advertise or even open the contents of a link to a file download from an unknown source. I found some information online saying that by using the Java Programming Language, I could run an application from a webpage using something called an "applet" that other people could access.

So I learned a second programming language and some basic html and tried to put my application on a website... Except it turns out that applets are a dying technology that no one trusts and that while it *is* possible to run a program as an applet (or a java web start application) from a webpage, modern browsers will scream bloody murder at anyone who tries to do so because applets are considered horribly insecure.

This project has now been ongoing in some form or another for over a year at this point, and I am at my wits end. I really, *really* don't want to have to write my program over again in yet another language just so that I can show it to people without them flipping out and acting like I'm trying to infect them with a virus. Is there any way at all to have people use my Java program for free on the internet in a way that won't give people terrible security messages?

Comment: Yes, you can create an [`applet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/).  You will, however, face security issues, since applets are limited in what they can do on users' computers.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: I've already tried that, in fact I detailed trying and being unsatisfied with both applets and java web start applications thoroughly in the body of my question.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it **after** I posted my comment.  Your "*something called an "applet"*" made me think that you are not familiar with the subject.

Comment: Fair enough, do you know of anything else I could use?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it better suits programmers.stackexchange.com site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a question of programming language. As long as your goal is to `distribute your code` (meaning that users have to download your code and run it on their computers) you will face the resistance.  I, for one, would not run anything downloaded from internet until I research it and find reputable evidence of it being legit and harmless.

You may want to have it as a `web application` that runs on **your** server and gives users options to download results in some acceptable format.  PDF is usually considered safe, though it's possible to embed maleware there.

[`Java EE`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html) gives many options for creation of such app, starting with [`JSP`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html) (Java Server Pages) and including more up-to-date ones ([`JSF`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html) and such).

Comment: Would I have to rewrite my program code (currently in the form of a java applet) to use such a technology?

Comment: Yes, you will need to rewrite the presentation layer, business logic stays the same (you can still use plain Java classes in JAVA EE application).  You also will need to obtain a place on an application server, which probably wouldn't be free.

Comment: Would JBoss, or Glassfish work?

Comment: `GlassFish` will work.  You will, however, need a physical box connectet to Internet to run on.  Unless you have your own infrastructure, someone will have to **host** your app. It *could* be the same company that hosts your domain.

Comment: Also, would you be able to link to a webpage that describes how to make GUI components using that technology (I presume by presentation layer you mean the class that creates the GUI)?

Comment: All highlighted words in my last paragraph are links.

Comment: You can play with local installation of `GlassFish` on your computer and use `localhost` URL for access.